# How to insert newlines on argparse help text?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using [`argparse` in Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) for parsing input options. One of my options is a multiple choice. I want to make a list in its help text, e.g.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description='test')

parser.add_argument('-g', choices=['a', 'b', 'g', 'd', 'e'], default='a',
    help="Some option, where\n"
         " a = alpha\n"
         " b = beta\n"
         " g = gamma\n"
         " d = delta\n"
         " e = epsilon")

parser.parse_args()
```

However, `argparse` strips all newlines and consecutive spaces. The result looks like

```
~/Downloads:52$ python2.7 x.py -h
usage: x.py [-h] [-g {a,b,g,d,e}]

test

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  -g {a,b,g,d,e}  Some option, where a = alpha b = beta g = gamma d = delta e
                  = epsilon
```

How to insert newlines in the help text?

Comment: I don't have python 2.7 with me so I can test out my ideas. How about using help text in triple quotes (""" """). Do the new lines survive using this?

Comment: @pyfunc: No. The stripping is done in runtime by `argparse`, not the interpreter, so switching to `"""..."""` won't help.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29485128/4288043) worked for me

Answer (score 584, accepted):

Try using [`RawTextHelpFormatter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter) to preserve all of your formatting:

```
from argparse import RawTextHelpFormatter
parser = ArgumentParser(description='test', formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
```

It's similar to [`RawDescriptionHelpFormatter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter) but instead of only applying to the description and epilog, `RawTextHelpFormatter` also applies to all help text (including arguments).

Comment: I think it's not.  You could subclass it, but unfortunately


    `Only the name of this class is considered a public API. All the methods provided by the class are considered an implementation detail.`  So probably not a great idea, although it might not matter, since 2.7 is meant to be the last 2.x python and you'll be expected to refactor lots of things for 3.x anyway.  I'm actually running 2.6 with `argparse` installed via `easy_install` so that documentation may itself be out of date.

Comment: Some links: for [python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#formatter-class), and [python 3.*](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#formatter-class). The 2.6 package should, according to [its wiki](http://code.google.com/p/argparse/), comply with the official 2.7 one. From the doc: "Passing RawDescriptionHelpFormatter as formatter_class= indicates that description and epilog are already correctly formatted and should not be line-wrapped"

Comment: Try instead formatter_class=`RawDescriptionHelpFormatter` which only works on description and epilog rather than help text.

Comment: I have noticed that even with `RawTextHelpFormatter`, leading and trailing newlines are removed. To work around this, you can simply add two or more consecutive newlines; all but one newline will survive.

Comment: You can combine formatters too, e.g. `class Formatter(
    argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
    argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter): pass` and then `formatter_class=Formatter`.

Comment: This is not working out for me (using python 3.6.8 on Ubuntu Linux 18.10). The linebreaks still don't show up, it's all one justified text block.

Comment: I found my mistake there: If subparsers are used (add_subparsers, later add_parser to define the subparser), the formatter_class has to be re-specified for each subparser

Comment: On the other hand, be it `RawDescriptionHelpFormatter` or `RawTextHelpFormatter`, it doesn’t strip leading indentation and doesn’t reflow text. This dumps the doc-string literally.

Answer (score 103):

If you just want to override the one option, you should not use `RawTextHelpFormatter`. Instead subclass the `HelpFormatter` and provide a special intro for the options that should be handled "raw" (I use `"R|rest of help"`):

```
import argparse

class SmartFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):

    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        if text.startswith('R|'):
            return text[2:].splitlines()  
        # this is the RawTextHelpFormatter._split_lines
        return argparse.HelpFormatter._split_lines(self, text, width)
```

And use it:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description='test', formatter_class=SmartFormatter)

parser.add_argument('-g', choices=['a', 'b', 'g', 'd', 'e'], default='a',
    help="R|Some option, where\n"
         " a = alpha\n"
         " b = beta\n"
         " g = gamma\n"
         " d = delta\n"
         " e = epsilon")

parser.parse_args()
```

Any other calls to `.add_argument()` where the help does not start with `R|` will be wrapped as normal.

This is part of [my improvements on argparse](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/std.argparse). The full SmartFormatter also supports adding
the defaults to all options, and raw input of the utilities description. The full version
has its own `_split_lines` method, so that any formatting done to e.g. version strings is preserved:

```
parser.add_argument('--version', '-v', action="version",
                    version="version...\n   42!")
```

Comment: I want to do this for a version message, but this SmartFormatter only seems to work with help text, not the special version text. `parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version',version=get_version_str())`

Is it possible to extend it to that case?

Comment: @mc_electron the full version of the SmartFormatter also has its own `_split_lines` and preserves line breaks (no need to specify "R|" at the beginning, if you want that option, patch the `_VersionAction.__call__` method

Comment: I'm not entirely grokking the first part of your comment, although I can see in `_VersionAction.__call__` that I would probably want it to just `parser.exit(message=version)` instead of using the formatted version. Is there any way to do that without releasing a patched copy of argparse though?

Comment: @mc_electron I am referring to the improvements I published on bitbucket (as per the link to my improvements on argparse in the answer). But  you can also patch the `__call__` in `_VersionAction` by doing `argparse._VersionAction.__call__ = smart_version` after defining `def smart_version(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None): ...`

Comment: Great idea. Didn't help me as the epilog and description don't seem to run through _split_lines :(

Comment: Hey this is sweet!  Though not present in the source code for the full version, the comment at the top of `_split_lines` that says `# this is the RawTextHelpFormatter._split_lines` is a little misleading.  The comment may be less confusing if you move it to below the `if` statement since that is the original `RawTextHelpFormatter` return.  Regardless, this answer gave me exactly what I needed, thanks again!

Comment: Really like this solution, but I feel it's more elegant to only apply this when a new line is found in the help text, sorta like this:

`class SmartFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        if '\n' in text:
            return text.splitlines()
        return argparse.HelpFormatter._split_lines(self, text, width)`

Sorry not sure how to preserve spaces in a reply here :)

Comment: Or this way (to split by double line breaks, like in TeX):
`def _split_lines(self, text, width):
  return [sln for ln in text.split('\n\n') for sln in argparse.HelpFormatter._split_lines(self, ln, width)]`

Answer (score 44):

Another easy way to do it is to include **[textwrap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html)**.

For example,

```
import argparse, textwrap
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='some information',
        usage='use "python %(prog)s --help" for more information',
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument('--argument', default=somedefault, type=sometype,
        help= textwrap.dedent('''\
        First line
        Second line
        More lines ... '''))
```

In this way, we can avoid the long empty space in front of each output line.

```
usage: use "python your_python_program.py --help" for more information

Prepare input file

optional arguments:
-h, --help            show this help message and exit
--argument ARGUMENT
                      First line
                      Second line
                      More lines ...
```

Answer (score 16):

I've faced similar issue (Python 2.7.6). I've tried to break down **description** section into several lines using `RawTextHelpFormatter`:

```
parser = ArgumentParser(description="""First paragraph 

                                       Second paragraph

                                       Third paragraph""",  
                                       usage='%(prog)s [OPTIONS]', 
                                       formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)

options = parser.parse_args()
```

And got:

```
usage: play-with-argparse.py [OPTIONS]

First paragraph 

                        Second paragraph

                        Third paragraph

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

So `RawTextHelpFormatter` is not a solution. Because it prints description as it appears in source code, preserving all whitespace characters (I want to keep extra tabs in my source code for readability but I don't want to print them all. Also raw formatter doesn't wrap line when it is too long, more than 80 characters for example).

Thanks to @Anton who inspired the right direction [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22157136/4672928). But that solution needs slight modification in order to format **description** section.

Anyway, custom formatter is needed. I extended existing `HelpFormatter` class and overrode `_fill_text` method like this:

```
import textwrap as _textwrap
class MultilineFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def _fill_text(self, text, width, indent):
        text = self._whitespace_matcher.sub(' ', text).strip()
        paragraphs = text.split('|n ')
        multiline_text = ''
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            formatted_paragraph = _textwrap.fill(paragraph, width, initial_indent=indent, subsequent_indent=indent) + '\n\n'
            multiline_text = multiline_text + formatted_paragraph
        return multiline_text
```

Compare with the original source code coming from [argparse](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/argparse.py#l620) module:

```
def _fill_text(self, text, width, indent):
    text = self._whitespace_matcher.sub(' ', text).strip()
    return _textwrap.fill(text, width, initial_indent=indent,
                                       subsequent_indent=indent)
```

In the original code the whole description is being wrapped. In custom formatter above the whole text is split into several chunks, and each of them is formatted independently.

So with aid of custom formatter:

```
parser = ArgumentParser(description= """First paragraph 
                                        |n                              
                                        Second paragraph
                                        |n
                                        Third paragraph""",  
                usage='%(prog)s [OPTIONS]',
                formatter_class=MultilineFormatter)

options = parser.parse_args()
```

the output is:

```
usage: play-with-argparse.py [OPTIONS]

First paragraph

Second paragraph

Third paragraph

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: This is wonderful --- happened on this after almost giving up and contemplating just reimplementing the help argument altogether... saved me a good amount of hassle.

Comment: subclassing `HelpFormatter` is problematic since the argparse developers only guarantee that the class name will survive in future versions of argparse. They've basically written themselves a blank check so they can change method names if it would be convenient for them to do so. I find this frustrating; the least they could have done is exposed a few methods in the API.

Comment: Not quite what the OP was asking for, but *exactly* what I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I admit I found this a very frustrating experience as it seems many others have, given the number of solutions I see posted and the number of times I see this asked across the web. But I find most of these solutions far too complicated for my likes and I'd like share the tersest simplest solution I have for it.

Here is the script to demonstrate:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import textwrap
from argparse import ArgumentParser, HelpFormatter

class RawFormatter(HelpFormatter):
    def _fill_text(self, text, width, indent):
        return "\n".join([textwrap.fill(line, width) for line in textwrap.indent(textwrap.dedent(text), indent).splitlines()])

program_descripton = f'''
    FunkyTool v1.0

    Created by the Funky Guy on January 1 2020
    Copyright 2020. All rights reserved.

    Licensed under The Hippocratic License 2.1
    https://firstdonoharm.dev/

    Distributed on an "AS IS" basis without warranties
    or conditions of any kind, either express or implied.

    USAGE:
    '''

parser = ArgumentParser(description=program_descripton, formatter_class=RawFormatter)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

And here is what it looks like in `test.py`:

```
$ ./test.py --help
usage: test.py [-h]

FunkyTool v1.0

Created by the Funky Guy on January 1 2020
Copyright 2020. All rights reserved.

Licensed under The Hippocratic License 2.1
https://firstdonoharm.dev/

Distributed on an "AS IS" basis without warranties
or conditions of any kind, either express or implied.

USAGE:

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

And so, all the basic formatting in the original description is preserved neatly and we've had, alas, to use a custom formatter, but it's a oneliner. It can be written more lucidly as:

```py
class RawFormatter(HelpFormatter):
    def _fill_text(self, text, width, indent):
        text = textwrap.dedent(text)          # Strip the indent from the original python definition that plagues most of us.
        text = textwrap.indent(text, indent)  # Apply any requested indent.
        text = text.splitlines()              # Make a list of lines
        text = [textwrap.fill(line, width) for line in text] # Wrap each line 
        text = "\n".join(text)                # Join the lines again
        return text
```

But I prefer it on one line myself.

Comment: This is a great answer! But it doesn't apply to the argument help text in OP's question. I added that functionality [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74368128/79125).

Answer (score 11):

Yet another simple way of getting new lines using `RawTextHelpFormatter` and deal with the indentation is

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='test', formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument('-g', choices=['a', 'b', 'g', 'd', 'e'], default='a',
                    help=('Some option, where\n'
                          ' a = alpha\n'
                          ' b = beta\n'
                          ' g = gamma\n'
                          ' d = delta\n'
                          ' e = epsilon'))

parser.parse_args()
```

The output is

```
$ python2 x.py -h
usage: x.py [-h] [-g {a,b,g,d,e}]

test

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  -g {a,b,g,d,e}  Some option, where
                   a = alpha
                   b = beta
                   g = gamma
                   d = delta
                   e = epsilon
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting from SmartFomatter described above, I ended to that solution:

```
class SmartFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    '''
         Custom Help Formatter used to split help text when '\n' was 
         inserted in it.
    '''

    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        r = []
        for t in text.splitlines(): r.extend(argparse.HelpFormatter._split_lines(self, t, width))
        return r
```

Note that strangely the formatter_class argument passed to top level parser is not inheritated by sub_parsers, one must pass it again for each created sub_parser.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to have both manual line breaks in the description text, and auto wrapping of it; but none of the suggestions here worked for me - so I ended up modifying the SmartFormatter class given in the answers here; the issues with the argparse method names not being a public API notwithstanding, here is what I have (as a file called `test.py`):

```
import argparse
from argparse import RawDescriptionHelpFormatter

# call with: python test.py -h

class SmartDescriptionFormatter(argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter):
  #def _split_lines(self, text, width): # RawTextHelpFormatter, although function name might change depending on Python
  def _fill_text(self, text, width, indent): # RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, although function name might change depending on Python
    #print("splot",text)
    if text.startswith('R|'):
      paragraphs = text[2:].splitlines()
      rebroken = [argparse._textwrap.wrap(tpar, width) for tpar in paragraphs]
      #print(rebroken)
      rebrokenstr = []
      for tlinearr in rebroken:
        if (len(tlinearr) == 0):
          rebrokenstr.append("")
        else:
          for tlinepiece in tlinearr:
            rebrokenstr.append(tlinepiece)
      #print(rebrokenstr)
      return '\n'.join(rebrokenstr) #(argparse._textwrap.wrap(text[2:], width))
    # this is the RawTextHelpFormatter._split_lines
    #return argparse.HelpFormatter._split_lines(self, text, width)
    return argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter._fill_text(self, text, width, indent)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=SmartDescriptionFormatter, description="""R|Blahbla bla blah blahh/blahbla (bla blah-blabla) a blahblah bl a blaha-blah .blah blah

Blah blah bla blahblah, bla blahblah blah blah bl blblah bl blahb; blah bl blah bl bl a blah, bla blahb bl:

  blah blahblah blah bl blah blahblah""")

options = parser.parse_args()
```

This is how it works in 2.7 and 3.4:

```
$ python test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h]

Blahbla bla blah blahh/blahbla (bla blah-blabla) a blahblah bl a blaha-blah
.blah blah

Blah blah bla blahblah, bla blahblah blah blah bl blblah bl blahb; blah bl
blah bl bl a blah, bla blahb bl:

  blah blahblah blah bl blah blahblah

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## Preface

For this question, `argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter` is helpful to me.

Now, I want to share how do I use the `argparse`.

I know it may not be related to question,

but these questions have been bothered me for a while.

So I want to share my experience, hope that will be helpful for someone.

Here we go.

## 3rd Party Modules

[colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/): for change the text color: `pip install colorama`

> Makes ANSI escape character sequences (for producing colored terminal text and cursor positioning) work under MS Windows

## Example

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back
from pathlib import Path
from os import startfile, system

SCRIPT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
TEMPLATE_DIR = SCRIPT_DIR.joinpath('.')


def main(args):
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    colorama.init(autoreset=True)

    from argparse import ArgumentParser, RawTextHelpFormatter

    format_text = FormatText([(20, '<'), (60, '<')])
    yellow_dc = format_text.new_dc(fore_color=Fore.YELLOW)
    green_dc = format_text.new_dc(fore_color=Fore.GREEN)
    red_dc = format_text.new_dc(fore_color=Fore.RED, back_color=Back.LIGHTYELLOW_EX)

    script_description = \
        '\n'.join([desc for desc in
                   [f'\n{green_dc(f"python {Path(__file__).name} [REFERENCE TEMPLATE] [OUTPUT FILE NAME]")} to create template.',
                    f'{green_dc(f"python {Path(__file__).name} -l *")} to get all available template',
                    f'{green_dc(f"python {Path(__file__).name} -o open")} open template directory so that you can put your template file there.',
                    # <- add your own description
                    ]])
    arg_parser = ArgumentParser(description=yellow_dc('CREATE TEMPLATE TOOL'),
                                # conflict_handler='resolve',
                                usage=script_description, formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)

    arg_parser.add_argument("ref", help="reference template", nargs='?')
    arg_parser.add_argument("outfile", help="output file name", nargs='?')
    arg_parser.add_argument("action_number", help="action number", nargs='?', type=int)
    arg_parser.add_argument('--list', "-l", dest='list',
                            help=f"example: {green_dc('-l *')} \n"
                                 "description: list current available template. (accept regex)")

    arg_parser.add_argument('--option', "-o", dest='option',
                            help='\n'.join([format_text(msg_data_list) for msg_data_list in [
                                ['example', 'description'],
                                [green_dc('-o open'), 'open template directory so that you can put your template file there.'],
                                [green_dc('-o run'), '...'],
                                [green_dc('-o ...'), '...'],
                                # <- add your own description
                            ]]))

    g_args = arg_parser.parse_args()
    task_run_list = [[False, lambda: startfile('.')] if g_args.option == 'open' else None,
                     [False, lambda: [print(template_file_path.stem) for template_file_path in TEMPLATE_DIR.glob(f'{g_args.list}.py')]] if g_args.list else None,
                     # <- add your own function
                     ]
    for leave_flag, func in [task_list for task_list in task_run_list if task_list]:
        func()
        if leave_flag:
            exit(0)

    # CHECK POSITIONAL ARGUMENTS
    for attr_name, value in vars(g_args).items():
        if attr_name.startswith('-') or value is not None:
            continue
        system('cls')
        print(f'error required values of {red_dc(attr_name)} is None')
        print(f"if you need help, please use help command to help you: {red_dc(f'python {__file__} -h')}")
        exit(-1)
    main(g_args)
```

Where the class of `FormatText` is the following

```
class FormatText:
    __slots__ = ['align_list']

    def __init__(self, align_list: list, autoreset=True):
        """
        USAGE::

            format_text = FormatText([(20, '<'), (60, '<')])
            red_dc = format_text.new_dc(fore_color=Fore.RED)
            print(red_dc(['column 1', 'column 2']))
            print(red_dc('good morning'))
        :param align_list:
        :param autoreset:
        """
        self.align_list = align_list
        colorama.init(autoreset=autoreset)

    def __call__(self, text_list: list):
        if len(text_list) != len(self.align_list):
            if isinstance(text_list, str):
                return text_list
            raise AttributeError
        return ' '.join(f'{txt:{flag}{int_align}}' for txt, (int_align, flag) in zip(text_list, self.align_list))

    def new_dc(self, fore_color: Fore = Fore.GREEN, back_color: Back = ""):  # DECORATOR
        """create a device context"""
        def wrap(msgs):
            return back_color + fore_color + self(msgs) + Fore.RESET
        return wrap
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

# 12 years late to the party, but I needed this too.

OP asked for new lines in *help* (not *description*) and as such the solutions here actually do not *fully* work, because if a line is longer than the screen width then it loses indentation when wrapped (gets wrapped to column 1 instead of preserving indentation of help text) which looks really ugly, or empty lines are gobbled, which I don't want as I need empty lines sometimes in long help texts.

Working solution below:

```py
import textwrap

class CustomHelpFormatter(argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter):
    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=width)
        lines = []
        for line in text.splitlines():
            if len(line) > width:
                lines.extend(wrapper.wrap(line))
            else:
                lines.append(line)
        return lines

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=CustomArgumentFormatter)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following python 3 formatter appends the default value if one exists and preserves line lengths.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter, \ 
                     RawTextHelpFormatter
import textwrap

class CustomArgumentFormatter(ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter, RawTextHelpFormatter):
    """Formats argument help which maintains line length restrictions as well as appends default value if present."""

    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        text = super()._split_lines(text, width)
        new_text = []

        # loop through all the lines to create the correct wrapping for each line segment.
        for line in text:
            if not line:
                # this would be a new line.
                new_text.append(line)
                continue

            # wrap the line's help segment which preserves new lines but ensures line lengths are
            # honored
            new_text.extend(textwrap.wrap(line, width))

        return new_text
```

Then create your argument parser with your new formatter:

```
my_arg_parser = ArgumentParser(formatter_class=CustomArgumentFormatter)
# ... add your arguments ...
print(my_arg_parser.format_help())
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for way to get the behavior of `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` but with newlines and tabs honored. Troy's code code got me close, but the final result ended up being a bit simpler:

```
class CustomArgumentFormatter(argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter):
    """
    Formats help text to honor newlines and tabs (and show default values).
    """

    # Match multiples of regular spaces only.
    _SPACE_MATCHER = re.compile(r' +', re.ASCII)

    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        new_text = []
        for line in text.splitlines():
          # For each newline in the help message, replace any multiples of
          # whitespaces (due to indentation in source code) with one space.
          line = self._SPACE_MATCHER.sub(' ', line).rstrip()
          # Fit the line length to the console width
          new_text.extend(textwrap.wrap(line, width))
        return new_text
```

Then newlines and tabs will appear as intended:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=CustomArgumentFormatter)

parser.add_argument(
    '--ethernet_config', type=str, required=False, default=None,
    help='Path to a text file that specifies Ethernet network IP settings \
      to use on the board. For example: \
      \n\t ip=192.0.2.100 \
      \n\t subnet_mask=255.255.255.0 \
      \n\t gateway=192.0.2.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bernd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64102901/79125) is very helpful, but doesn't apply to argument help strings. Here's an extension of it that applies to all help text (following the [example of RawTextHelpFormatter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2eee9d9cd7eb1e396fa9a4af7c5fadeeafbdaa38/Lib/argparse.py#L680)).

DescriptionWrappedNewlineFormatter is his original RawFormatter and WrappedNewlineFormatter will additionally wrap arguments.

```py
import argparse
import textwrap

class DescriptionWrappedNewlineFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    """An argparse formatter that:
    * preserves newlines (like argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter),
    * removes leading indent (great for multiline strings),
    * and applies reasonable text wrapping.

    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64102901/79125
    """
    def _fill_text(self, text, width, indent):
        # Strip the indent from the original python definition that plagues most of us.
        text = textwrap.dedent(text)
        text = textwrap.indent(text, indent)  # Apply any requested indent.
        text = text.splitlines()  # Make a list of lines
        text = [textwrap.fill(line, width) for line in text]  # Wrap each line
        text = "\n".join(text)  # Join the lines again
        return text


class WrappedNewlineFormatter(DescriptionWrappedNewlineFormatter):
    """An argparse formatter that:
    * preserves newlines (like argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter),
    * removes leading indent and applies reasonable text wrapping (like DescriptionWrappedNewlineFormatter),
    * applies to all help text (description, arguments, epilogue).
    """
    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        # Allow multiline strings to have common leading indentation.
        text = textwrap.dedent(text)
        text = text.splitlines()
        lines = []
        for line in text:
            wrapped_lines = textwrap.fill(line, width).splitlines()
            lines.extend(subline for subline in wrapped_lines)
            if line:
                lines.append("")  # Preserve line breaks.
        return lines


if __name__ == "__main__":
    def demo_formatter(formatter):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description="""
                A program that does things.
                Lots of description that describes how the program works.

                very long lines are wrapped. very long lines are wrapped. very long lines are wrapped. very long lines are wrapped. very long lines are wrapped. very long lines are wrapped.

                existing wrapping will be preserved if within width. existing
                wrapping is preserved. existing wrapping will be preserved.
                existing wrapping is preserved. existing wrapping will be
                preserved. existing wrapping is preserved. existing wrapping
                will be preserved. existing wrapping is preserved unless it goes too long for the display width.
                """,
            formatter_class=formatter,
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            "--option",
            choices=[
                "red",
                "blue",
            ],
            help="""
                Lots of text describing different choices.
                    red: a warning colour
                    text on the next line

                    blue: a longer blah blah keeps going going going going going going going going going going
                """,
        )
        print("\n\nDemo for {}\n".format(formatter.__name__))
        parser.print_help()

    demo_formatter(DescriptionWrappedNewlineFormatter)
    demo_formatter(WrappedNewlineFormatter)
```

## Demo output for WrappedNewlineFormatter

```
usage: arg.py [-h] [--option {red,blue}]

A program that does things.
Lots of description that describes how the program works.

very long lines are wrapped. very long lines are wrapped. very long lines are
wrapped. very long lines are wrapped. very long lines are wrapped. very long
lines are wrapped.

existing wrapping will be preserved if within width. existing
wrapping is preserved. existing wrapping will be preserved.
existing wrapping is preserved. existing wrapping will be
preserved. existing wrapping is preserved. existing wrapping
will be preserved. existing wrapping is preserved unless it goes too long for
the display width.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
                       
  --option {red,blue}  Lots of text describing different choices.
                       
                           red: a warning colour
                       
                           text on the next line
                       
                           blue: a longer blah blah keeps going going going
                       going going going going going going going
```

## Demo output for DescriptionWrappedNewlineFormatter

````
usage: arg.py [-h] [--option {red,blue}]

A program that does things.
Lots of description that describes how the program works.

very long lines are wrapped. very long lines are wrapped. very long lines are
wrapped. very long lines are wrapped. very long lines are wrapped. very long
lines are wrapped.

existing wrapping will be preserved if within width. existing
wrapping is preserved. existing wrapping will be preserved.
existing wrapping is preserved. existing wrapping will be
preserved. existing wrapping is preserved. existing wrapping
will be preserved. existing wrapping is preserved unless it goes too long for
the display width.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --option {red,blue}  Lots of text describing different choices. red: a
                       warning colour text on the next line blue: a longer
                       blah blah keeps going going going going going going
                       going going going going
                       ```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution I found that keeps the ability to automatically wrap text to the terminal's with while keeping manual newlines intact. It boils down to replacing the default formatter's calls to `textwrap.wrap()` with a version that keeps the manual newlines.

The `_split_lines()` and `_fill_text()` that I've overridden are of course implementation details of `argparse`, so this might break in the future. I'd be glad if you note so in the comments, if that happens to you!

```py
import textwrap
from argparse import ArgumentParser, HelpFormatter


def wrap_paragraphs(text: str, width: int, indent: str):
    """
    Wrapper around `textwrap.wrap()` which keeps newlines in the input string
    intact.
    """
    lines = list[str]()

    for i in text.splitlines():
        paragraph_lines = \
            textwrap.wrap(i, width, initial_indent=indent, subsequent_indent=indent)

        # `textwrap.wrap()` will return an empty list when passed an empty
        # string (which happens when there are two consecutive line breaks in
        # the input string). This would lead to those line breaks being
        # collapsed into a single line break, effectively removing empty lines
        # from the input. Thus, we add an empty line in that case.
        lines.extend(paragraph_lines or [''])

    return lines


class Formatter(HelpFormatter):
    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        return wrap_paragraphs(text, width, '')

    def _fill_text(self, text, width, indent):
        return '\n'.join(wrap_paragraphs(text, width, indent))


parser = ArgumentParser(
    prog='guide',
    formatter_class=Formatter,
    description='The Hitch Hiker\'s Guide to the Galaxy is a wholly remarkable '
                'book. It has been compiled and recompiled many times over '
                'many years and under many different editorships. It contains'
                'contributions from countless numbers of travellers and '
                'researchers.\n'
                '\n'
                'The introduction begins like this:\n'
                '\n'
                '"Space," it says "is big. Really big"\n')

parser.add_argument(
    '--probability',
    help='"But what does it mean?" cried Arthur.\n'
         '"What, the custard?"\n'
         '"No, the measurement of probability!"\n')


parser.print_help()
```

```
usage: guide [-h] [--probability PROBABILITY]

The Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy is a wholly remarkable book. It has been
compiled and recompiled many times over many years and under many different
editorships. It containscontributions from countless numbers of travellers and
researchers.

The introduction begins like this:

"Space," it says "is big. Really big"

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --probability PROBABILITY
                        "But what does it mean?" cried Arthur.
                        "What, the custard?"
                        "No, the measurement of probability!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution that's pretty similar to some of the suggested ones which preserves newlines and leading whitespace. The only catch is that it converts tabs to 4 spaces so that their impact on the width can be predicted.

The main difference between this approach and the previous suggestions is that it delegates all of the formatting to the parent methods. It doesn't require knowledge of `textwrap` or really anything else from the base class besides some private method names.

```
from argparse import HelpFormatter

def lws(line):
    prefix = line[:len(line) - len(line.lstrip())]
    return len(prefix) + 3 * prefix.count('\t')

class SmartHelpFormatter(HelpFormatter):
    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        r = []
        for line in lines():
            n = lws(line)
            r.extend(' ' * n + s for s in super()._split_lines(line, width - n))
        return r

    def _fill_text(self, text, width, indent):
        r = []
        for line in text.splitlines():
            n = lws(line)
            r.append(super()._fill_text(line, width, indent + ' ' * n))
        return '\n'.join(r)
```

You can find a slightly more flexible version of this in [`haggis.args.SmartHelpFormatter`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.args.SmartHelpFormatter) (which I wrote and maintain).