# Python argparse: Preformatted help text?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse and I want to display a list in the help text of one of my options. However, argparse strips new lines from the text and displays it on a single line.

Is there anyway to tell argparse that the help string is preformatted, and not to strip new line characters?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853722/python-argparse-how-to-insert-newline-the-help-text ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#formatter-class):

> RawTextHelpFormatter maintains
>   whitespace for all sorts of help text
>   including argument descriptions.

```
from argparse import RawTextHelpFormatter
parser = ArgumentParser(description='test', formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
```

Comment: is there any way to do this for a single option? it messes up the word wrapping for the others

Comment: just read @barti_ddu's link. my comment is a dupe too. thanks

Comment: Yes, this question has already been answered but I read his comment after posting and so I thought to let it stay :)

Comment: And if you only want pre-formatting to apply to the program *description*, use [`RawDescriptionHelpFormatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#formatter-class), which has been in Python since at least 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to override the one option, you cannot use `RawTextHelpFormatter`. Instead subclass the `HelpFormatter` and provide a special intro for the options that should be handled "raw" (I use `"R|rest of help"`):

```
import argparse

class SmartFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):

    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        # this is the RawTextHelpFormatter._split_lines
        if text.startswith('R|'):
            return text[2:].splitlines()  
        return argparse.HelpFormatter._split_lines(self, text, width)
```

And use it:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from textwrap import dedent

parser = ArgumentParser(description='test')

parser.add_argument('--list', help=dedent("""\
    R|abc
      def
        ghi
"""))
parser.parse_args()
```

Any other calls to `.add_argument()` where the help does not start with `R|` will be wrapped as normal.

This is part of [my improvements on argparse](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/std.argparse). The full SmartFormatter also supports adding
the defaults to all options, and raw input of the utilities description.