# How can I print a Python file's docstring when executing it?

Tags: python, docstring

I have a Python script with a docstring. When the parsing of the command-line arguments does not succeed, I want to print the docstring for the user's information.

Is there any way to do this?

### Minimal example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Usage: script.py

This describes the script.
"""

import sys


if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("<here comes the docstring>")
```

Comment: There are libraries for cmdline argument parsing: argparse (>=2.7) and optparse. http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html http://docs.python.org/dev/library/optparse.html

Comment: I know that but it's not relevant to the question

Comment: I am one person who sometimes explicitly does *not* want to use argparse for a really simple script, so I'm grateful for those below who answered the question as asked.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The docstring is stored in the module's `__doc__` global.

```
print(__doc__)
```

By the way, this goes for any module: `import sys; print(sys.__doc__)`. Docstrings of functions and classes are also in their `__doc__` attribute.

Comment: That definitely works, but there is another way that shows a more native looking module help interface::  `help(module_name)` after you import that module.

Comment: @danbgray I think what you are getting at is what argparse is used for

Comment: WEIRD PYTHON 2 WRINKLE: If you put, e.g. "from \_\_future\_\_ import print_function" before the docstring, *it's not a docstring anymore*.  But you can put "from \_\_future\_\_" import... *just after* the docstring, and the "from \_\_future\_\_ imports must occur at the beginning of the file" rule is still satisfied.

Answer (score 19):

Argument parsing should always be done with [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html).

You can display the `__doc__` string by passing it to the `description` parameter of Argparse:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
This describes the script.
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from argparse import ArgumentParser
    parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    # Add your arguments here
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", dest="myFilenameVariable",
                        required=True,
                        help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.myFilenameVariable)
```

If you call this **mysuperscript.py** and execute it you get:

```
$ ./mysuperscript.py --help
usage: mysuperscript.py [-h] -f FILE

This describes the script.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f FILE, --file FILE  write report to FILE
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is an alternative that does not hardcode the script's filename, but instead uses sys.argv[0] to print it. Using %(scriptName)s instead of %s improves readability of the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Usage: %(scriptName)s

This describes the script.
"""

import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
   print __doc__ % {'scriptName' : sys.argv[0].split("/")[-1]}
   sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: thanks. I usually have a usage() function that uses sys.argv[0] which is called before printing the docstring.

Comment: @wint3rschlaefer, could you explain how Usage: %(scriptName)s get the script name? What is this mechanism called in python?

Comment: @wint3rschlaefer Maybe it's worth updating with a python3 version, like  `"""Usage: {scriptName}""".format(scriptName = sys.argv[0])`

Comment: How about using __name_ ?

Answer (score 1):

This will **print the `__doc__` string** when `--help` is the only argument.

```
if __name__=='__main__':
 if len(sys.argv)==2 and sys.argv[1]=='--help':
    print(__doc__)
```

Works for both:

- `./yourscriptname.py --help`
- `python3 yourscriptname.py --help`

Answer (score 1):

An enhancement of @MartinThoma's answer so it prints multi-line docstrings inspired by [Python argparse: How to insert newline in the help text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853722/python-argparse-how-to-insert-newline-in-the-help-text..).

> Argument parsing should always be done with argparse.
>
> You can display the **doc** string by passing it to the description
> parameter of Argparse:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python 
> """ 
> This summarizes the script.
>
> Additional descriptive paragraph(s).
> """  # Edited this docstring
>
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     from argparse import ArgumentParser, RawTextHelpFormatter  # Edited this line
>     parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__
>                             formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)  # Added this line
>     # Add your arguments here
>     parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", dest="myFilenameVariable",
>                         required=True,
>                         help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE")
>     args = parser.parse_args()
>     print(args.myFilenameVariable)
> ```
>
> If you call this mysuperscript.py and execute it you get:
>
> ```
> $ ./mysuperscript.py --help
> usage: mysuperscript.py [-h] -f FILE
>
> This summarizes the script.
>
> Additional descriptive paragraph(s).
>
> optional arguments:
>   -h, --help            show this help message and exit
>   -f FILE, --file FILE  write report to FILE
> ```

Without the addition of the `formatter_class` the output would not have the line break in the docstring.