# "Standardized" docstring/self-documentation of bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, documentation

## Background

Python scripts, for example, can have several "levels" of documentation via [`docstrings`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring). What's neat about it, is that they can be defined at per-function levels, per-method levels, per-class levels, and most importantly (in the context of my question): per-file levels. For example, the top of the file may look like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
@brief  A script that does cool stuff.
"""
```

[**What's especially useful about this feature is that it's easy to extract and print at run-time.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791574/how-can-i-print-a-python-files-docstring-when-executing-it)

---

## Question

Do [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) scripts support such a feature? i.e. is there a "standardized" approach to generating a file-level set of documentation (i.e. human-readable description of the purpose of the script, [`usage` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725675/is-there-a-standard-format-for-command-line-shell-help-text), etc.; so that it's easy for another script to automatically parse/extract this information? **My goal is to create several debug scripts that are self-documenting, and if there's already a standard/de-facto-best way to do this, I'd like to avoid re-inventing the wheel.**

Comment: Short answer: no, `bash` itself has nothing. That makes this a question about which 3rd-party tools that might follow some convention, which makes it off-topic.

Comment: For embedding/extracting man pages, [POD-style snippets](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-embed-documentation-in-bash-scripts) are quite good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard for docstrings for bash. It's always nice to have man pages though (eg. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-creating-a-manpage/), or info pages (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164443/how-to-create-info-documentation).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. While I would have preferred being able to have the documentation "baked in" to the script, this will suit my use case just fine.

Answer (score 9):

The "File Header" section of Google's [*Shell Style Guide*](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml#File_Header) is one way to add a 'docstring' to your bash scripts.

Basically, the answer is to use `#`, rather than quotes like you would with Python.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this for Bash easily, it is a little more tricky if you need to ensure compatibility with POSIX only shells like /bin/sh or primarily busybox systems like Alpine.

The Linux Documentation Project has some great examples.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

> Yet another twist of this nifty trick makes "self-documenting" scripts
>   possible.
>
> Example 19-12. A self-documenting script
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> # self-document.sh: self-documenting script
> # Modification of "colm.sh".
>
> DOC_REQUEST=70
>
> if [ "$1" = "-h"  -o "$1" = "--help" ]     # Request help.
> then
>   echo; echo "Usage: $0 [directory-name]"; echo
>   sed --silent -e '/DOCUMENTATIONXX$/,/^DOCUMENTATIONXX$/p' "$0" |
>   sed -e '/DOCUMENTATIONXX$/d'; exit $DOC_REQUEST; fi
>
>
> : <<DOCUMENTATIONXX
> List the statistics of a specified directory in tabular format.
> ---------------------------------------------------------------
> The command-line parameter gives the directory to be listed.
> If no directory specified or directory specified cannot be read,
> then list the current working directory.
>
> DOCUMENTATIONXX
>
> if [ -z "$1" -o ! -r "$1" ]
> then
>   directory=.
> else
>   directory="$1"
> fi  
>
> echo "Listing of "$directory":"; echo
> (printf "PERMISSIONS LINKS OWNER GROUP SIZE MONTH DAY HH:MM PROG-NAME\n" \
> ; ls -l "$directory" | sed 1d) | column -t
>
> exit 0
> ```
>
> Using a cat script is an alternate way of accomplishing this.
>
> ```
> DOC_REQUEST=70
>
> if [ "$1" = "-h"  -o "$1" = "--help" ]     # Request help.
> then                                       # Use a "cat script" . . .
>   cat <<DOCUMENTATIONXX
> List the statistics of a specified directory in tabular format.
> ---------------------------------------------------------------
> The command-line parameter gives the directory to be listed.
> If no directory specified or directory specified cannot be read,
> then list the current working directory.
>
> DOCUMENTATIONXX
> exit $DOC_REQUEST
> fi
> ```

A slightly more elegant example using functions to handle the documentation and error messages.

```
#!/bin/sh

usage() {
cat << EOF
Usage: 
  $0 [-u [username]] [-p]
  Options:
    -u <username> : Optionally specify the new username to set password for.  
    -p : Prompt for a new password.
EOF
}

die() {
  echo
  echo "$1, so giving up.  Sorry."
  echo
  exit 2
}

if [ -z "$USER" ] ; then
  die "Could not identify the existing user"
fi

if $PSET ; then
  passwd $USER || die "Busybox didn't like your password"
fi
```

https://github.com/jyellick/mficli/blob/master/util/changecreds.sh

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:` (null) built-in for bash functions loaded into your environment from a `.bashrc`-style include.

```bash
$ declare -f my_function
my_function() {
    : My function does this and that
    echo "foo"
}

$ my_function
foo

$ type my_function
my_function is a function
my_function () 
{ 
    : My function does this and that;
    echo "foo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I proposed a method for how to do bash docstrings in a [blog post](https://blog.aloni.org/posts/bash-docstrings/).

In short, use a non-executing function `__docstring__()`, and write a `help` commands that find all of these to print a help screen.

```bash
build() {
    __docstring__() {
        echo """<params>

        Build and work on stuff

        -j <core> - number of cores
        """
    }

    : # << your build implementation here >>
}
```