# Python argparse: How to insert newline the help text in subparser?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

This question is related to a [question asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853722/python-argparse-how-to-insert-newline-the-help-text), but might be unrelated. Question is: How to use newlines in the help text in the given (working) example below, when using subparsers?

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser_start = subparsers.add_parser('stop')
parser_start.add_argument("file", help = "firstline\nnext line\nlast line")

print parser.parse_args()
```

My output is as follows:

```
tester.py  stop -h
usage: tester.py stop [-h] file

positional arguments:
  file        firstline next line last line

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

The expected output for the help on `file` should be:

```
first line
next line
last line
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `subparsers.add_parser()` method takes the same `ArgumentParser` constructor arguments as `argparse.ArgumentParser()`.  So, to use the `RawTextHelpFormatter` for the subparser, you need to set the `formatter_class` explicitly when you add the subparser.

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
>>> subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
```

Change this line to set the `formatter_class` of the subparser:

```
>>> parser_start = subparsers.add_parser('stop', formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
```

Now, your help text will contain the newlines:

```
>>> parser_start.add_argument("file", help="firstline\nnext line\nlast line")
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='file', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='firstline\nnext line\nlast line', metavar=None)

>>> print parser.parse_args(['stop', '--help'])
usage:  stop [-h] file

positional arguments:
  file        firstline
              next line
              last line

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```