# Python argparse: Insert blank line between help entries

Tags: python, argparse

When using argparse, passing `--help` to the program generates help text. Unfortunately, it's hard to read because there are no blank lines between options. Here's an excerpt to illustrate:

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -u FILENAME, --up-sound FILENAME
                        The sound to play when the network comes up. Default:
                        "/path/to/some/sound/file.wav"
  -d FILENAME, --down-sound FILENAME
                        The sound to play when the network goes down. Default:
                        "/path/to/some/other/sound/file.wav"
  -p EXECUTABLE, --player EXECUTABLE
                        The program to use to play sounds. Default: "play"
  -s, --silent          If specified, network_monitor.py will not play any
                        sounds.
  -c, --no-clear-screen
                        If specified, screen will not be cleared (nor extra
                        blank lines added) before network_monitor.py runs.
  --version             show program's version number and exit
```

Notice that in some cases, such as between `-p` and `-s` or between `-c` and `--version`, it is difficult to tell at a glance which help text applies to which option. There should be a blank line between entries. For example:

```
  -p EXECUTABLE, --player EXECUTABLE
                        The program to use to play sounds. Default: "play"

  -s, --silent          If specified, network_monitor.py will not play any
                        sounds.
```

How can I accomplish this? [Several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3853722/713735) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15530575/713735) questions recommend using `argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter`. The problem with that is that if I use it, I have to write my own logic to wrap the help text as the raw text help formatter does no formatting. The obvious answer would be to append `'\n\n'` to the end of the help text and use the default formatter. But inexplicably, newlines get stripped.

What's the way forward here? I'm using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create your own help text formatter that does this. Note that this requires you to be very specific to the implementation detail of the `argparse.HelpFormatter`. So consider this warning that is included in every help formatter type description:

> Only the name of this class is considered a public API. All the methods provided by the class are considered an implementation detail.

Once we ignore that, creating our own help formatter that adds a blank line between the entries is very simple:

```
class BlankLinesHelpFormatter (argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        return super()._split_lines(text, width) + ['']
```

And that’s it. Now when you create the [`ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser) object while passing 
`formatter_class=BlankLinesHelpFormatter` to the constructor, blank lines will appear between each argument in the help text.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks. What do you suppose are the odds of this breaking in the future?

Comment: The [source file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/log/default/Lib/argparse.py) hasn’t been touched that often in the past, and most of those changes had no impact on the interface. So despite the warning, I would say you are pretty fine for quite a while. Plus, by just calling the base method, my solution doesn’t depend on much and doesn’t reinvents any of the logic that may break in the future.

Comment: `super(BlankLinesHelpFormatter, self)` for those of us who still haven't heard that Python 2.7 is end of life.

Answer (score 4):

`poke's` approach is good.  Note that `RawTextHelpFormatter` also modifies this method, simplifying it to:

```
def _split_lines(self, text, width):
    return text.splitlines()
```

`poke's` method could be tweaked to give you more control

```
class BlankLinesHelpFormatter (argparse.HelpFormatter):
    # add empty line if help ends with \n
    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        lines = super()._split_lines(text, width)
        if text.endswith('\n'):
            lines += ['']
        return lines
```

With this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A description',
    formatter_class=BlankLinesHelpFormatter,
    epilog='Epilog line',
    )
parser.add_argument('-u', '--up-sound', metavar='FILENAME',
    help='The sound to play when the network comes up. Default:"%(default)s"\n',
    default="/path/to/some/sound/file.wav")
# note \n in above help
parser.add_argument('-d', '--down-sound', metavar='FILENAME',
    help='The sound to play when the network goes down. Default:"%(default)s"',
    default="/path/to/some/other/sound/file.wav")
parser.add_argument('-s','--silent', action='store_true',
    help='If specified, network_monitor.py will not play any sounds.')
parser.add_argument('positional', nargs='*', help='positional argument')
parser.print_help()
```

displays:

```
usage: stack29484443.py [-h] [-u FILENAME] [-d FILENAME] [-s]
                        [positional [positional ...]]

A description

positional arguments:
  positional            positional argument

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -u FILENAME, --up-sound FILENAME
                        The sound to play when the network comes up.
                        Default:"/path/to/some/sound/file.wav"

  -d FILENAME, --down-sound FILENAME
                        The sound to play when the network goes down.
                        Default:"/path/to/some/other/sound/file.wav"
  -s, --silent          If specified, network_monitor.py will not play any
                        sounds.

Epilog line
```

For reference, the default `_split_lines` is:

```
def _split_lines(self, text, width):
    text = self._whitespace_matcher.sub(' ', text).strip()
    return _textwrap.wrap(text, width)
    # self._whitespace_matcher = _re.compile(r'\s+')
```

This removes final \n and reduces all interior whitespace to one blank.