# Set line length for output in Python's argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Currently I am using the following code to initialize my `ArgumentParser`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Help line 1\n" +
                                             "Help line 2",
                                 formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
```

Which, after adding some arguments, gives me the following output:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /data/Poseidon/dev/Python/trident.py -h
usage: trident.py [-h] [--verbose] [--images] --source SOURCE --network
                  NETWORK

Help line 1
Help line 2
```

I would rather not have the "NETWORK" argument in the "usage" part of the help output in the next line, but on the same line. Is there any way to tell `argparse` to **not** add newlines in the list of arguments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Help line 1\n" +
                                             "Help line 2",
                                 formatter_class=lambda prog: argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter(prog, width=99999))
```

If you do this, take note of this comment from `HelpFormatter.__doc__`:

> Only the name of this class is considered a public API. All the methods provided by the class are considered an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for me. As for the records, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613565/514149), another way to achieve this is to the set the `COLUMNS` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

The better resolution (comparing to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53283500/10418734) is

1. Create a class that formats with a desired width

```py
class _WidthFormatter(argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter):
    def __init__(self, prog: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(prog, width=99999)
```

2. And use the class

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=(
        "Help line 1\n"
        "Help line 2"
    ),
    formatter_class= _WidthFormatter
)
```

This solution is preferred as `formatter_class` argument in `argparse.ArgumentParser` expects to use a class, not a class instance.

Comment: I'm not sure what `Text` is meant to be in the above, but leaving it blank or using `str` seems fine. Using either answer, it successfully restricts the length of the line but I'm unable to expand it so the output from each option appears in a single line.

Comment: `from typing import Text`  - this type is the same as `str`. So, I updated the solution above. Thanks @Deepstop