# why '\n' doesn't work in help option of add_argument?

Tags: python

```
import argparse

my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='this is an example')
my_parser.add_argument('-pattern', '--list', nargs='+',
                       help='choose the properties as you need:\n'
                            'including:\n'
                            'power, area, toggle, performance')

pattern = my_parser.parse_args().list
print('example exit')
```

When I type `python help.py -h` in terminal, I found that `'\n'` doesn't work:

```
D:\py_prj\try>python help.py -h
usage: help.py [-h] [-pattern LIST [LIST ...]]

this is an example

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -pattern LIST [LIST ...], --list LIST [LIST ...]
                        choose the properties as you need: including: power,      
                        area, toggle, performance
```

Why?

Comment: try multiline string

Comment: @GhostOps How…?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613487/multiple-lines-in-python-argparse-help-display