# Django command: How to insert newline in the help text?

Tags: python, django, argparse

I was looking to do something like this, but for a Django management command:
[Python argparse: How to insert newline in the help text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853722/python-argparse-how-to-insert-newline-in-the-help-text)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.create_parser)

> You can customize the instance by overriding this method and calling super() with kwargs of ArgumentParser parameters.

By overriding `create_parser` method
you can set the `formatter_class` of the `ArgumentParser`:

```
from argparse import RawTextHelpFormatter
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def create_parser(self, *args, **kwargs):
        parser = super(Command, self).create_parser(*args, **kwargs)
        parser.formatter_class = RawTextHelpFormatter
        return parser
```

Comment: Sure would be nice to have multiline help text be the default for management commands project wide.

Comment: How do you apply this to `help_text`?

Comment: Unclear or partial answer. How to use this with `help_text`. Can you please state the elaborated answer

Comment: @alias51 and @ajinzrathod : under the `class Command(BaseCommand):`, add a `help = """some text ....."""` which can span multiple lines. thanks to the answer above (the custom `create_parser`), the `help` value will retain its line breaks. @seán-hayes thanks a lot -- this solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You can insert the new line in help_text by entering the HTML 
 tag

For e.g.

```
name=models.Charfield(max_length=10, help_text="Enter First name or <br/> Enter full name")
```

Comment: This is not for a django management command, but Model field help text to be displayed in admin.