# python argparse: my help, not auto-generated, but short help for single options

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way in [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html)
to print 
my help, not auto-generated, for `--help`,
but only the short `help=` for single options ?
An example:

```
    # my help, not auto-generated --
if len(sys.argv) >= 1  and sys.argv[1].startswith(( "-h", "--h" )):
    print __doc__
    sys.exit()

p = argparse.ArgumentParser( usage="" )

    # want to print only this short help= for e.g. `-help -col`
p.add_argument( "-col", default=1, type=int,
                        help="the column to look at and color, 1 2 3 ..." )

    # and only this help= for e.g. `-help -color`
p.add_argument( "-color", "-colour", default="red",
                        help="one of: r g b red green blue " )
```

~

Comment: What's the difference between your expected help message and the message generated by argparse?

Comment: Capturing the `help` right away is a good idea.  `ipython` does that.  And this way lets you distinguish between `-h` and `--help`.  Doing this within `argparse` is possible but would be a lot more work.

Comment: @Edgar Andrés Margffoy Tuay, mine is longer, has examples, what I want to convey to users -- ideally, a `man` page.

Comment: I don't know if implementing an instance of ``argparse.HelpFormatter`` might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853722/python-argparse-how-to-insert-newline-in-the-help-text