# pythons argparse: define choices in -h

Tags: python, argparse

I'm building a command line argparser for my program and I try to give much detail in the `-h` option

I have the following code:

```
import argparse
legal_actions = ['act1', 'act2', 'act3']
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='available commands')

    parser_cmd = subparsers.add_parser("cmd")

    parser_cmd.add_argument("-a", "--action", type=str, metavar="", choices=legal_actions, required=True,
                            help='list of actions: {%(choices)s}')
    parser_cmd.add_argument("nargs", type=str, nargs='*',
                            help="the rest of the arguments required to perform an action")
    parser_cmd.set_defaults(func=cmd_handler)
```

`python prog.py cmd -h` will result the following prints in the command line

```
usage: cmd [-h] -a  [nargs [nargs ...]]

positional arguments:
  nargs           the rest of the arguments required to perform an action

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  -a , --action   list of actions: {act1, act2, act3}
```

Every action requires a different number of arguments, so I want to add something that will describe the actions (from the list of actions) like:

```
actions availble:
    act1: requires 2 arguments (arg1, arg2)
    act2: requires 0 arguments ()
    act3: requires 1 arguments (arg1)
```

And I want it to have any link with the above "optional arguments", so it'll be easy to see the "acts" are under the -a option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add more information, you can use the `epilog`-parameter:

```
from argparse import RawDescriptionHelpFormatter  # This is used to enable newlines in epilogs and descriptions(\n)
from argparse import ArgumentParser

description = 'Some description of program'
epilog = 'actions availble:\n\t'
epilog += 'act1: requires 2 arguments (arg1, arg2)\n\t'
epilog += 'act2: requires 0 arguments ()\n\t'
epilog += 'act3: requires 1 arguments (arg1)'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=description, epilog=epilog, 
                                formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
```

This will print out

```
actions availble:
    act1: requires 2 arguments (arg1, arg2)
    act2: requires 0 arguments ()
    act3: requires 1 arguments (arg1)
```

At the end of help output. The `epilog`-parameter can also be included in the `add_parser()` when using `add_subparsers()`:

> This object has a single method, add_parser(), which takes a command name and any ArgumentParser constructor arguments, and returns an ArgumentParser object that can be modified as usual.

NOTE: the default formatter will ignore newlines, so take a look at [Python argparse: How to insert newline in the help text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853722/python-argparse-how-to-insert-newline-in-the-help-text) where this is addressed, which describe how to replace the formatter á la:

```
ArgumentParser(..., formatter_class=RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
```

Read more about the epilog-parameter in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#epilog).

Comment: `parser_cmd = subparsers.add_parser("cmd", epilog=epilog)` Will do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the `add_parser()` method will accept any arguments that the `ArgumentParser` initializer would. Glad it could be of use :)

Comment: damn. epilog completely ignore the '\n' and '\t' characters

Comment: Ah, yes, that might be an issue. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853722/python-argparse-how-to-insert-newline-in-the-help-text which might solve the newline issue

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your issue, does this help?

Comment: `parser_cmd = subparsers.add_parser("cmd", epilog=epilog, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                       help="run xgb_server from cmd line with cmd arguments")`. Notice that it has to be in parser_cmd, and in order to control description and epilogs, you have to use `argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter`