# Python Argparse - How can I add text to the default help message?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using python's argparse to handle parsing of arguments.
I get a default help message structured like so:

```
usage: ProgramName [-h] ...

Description

positional arguments:
  ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  ...
```

What I want is to add an entire new section to this message, for example:

```
usage: ProgramName [-h] ...

Description

positional arguments:
  ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  ...

additional information:
  This will show additional information relevant to the user.
  ....
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior?
A solution that is supported by both python 2.7 and 3.x is preferred.

Edit:
I would also rather have a solution that will add the new section / sections at the bottom of the help message.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can quite do it using [epilog](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#epilog).
Here is an example below:

```
import argparse
import textwrap
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      prog='ProgramName',
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      epilog=textwrap.dedent('''\
         additional information:
             I have indented it
             exactly the way
             I want it
         '''))
parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', help='foo help')
parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='+', help='bar help')
parser.print_help()
```

Result :

```
usage: ProgramName [-h] [--foo [FOO]] bar [bar ...]

positional arguments:
  bar          bar help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --foo [FOO]  foo help

additional information:
    I have indented it
    exactly the way
    I want it
```

Answer (score 29):

There are multiple ways in which you can [add a description](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#description) to your command.
The recommended way is to add a module documentation at the top of your source code file as in:

```
""" This is the description, it will be accessible within the variable
    __doc__
"""
```

And then:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
```

To add text below the parameter description, use epilog, as shown in the following example taken from the documentation:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A foo that bars',  
                                     epilog="And that's how you'd foo a bar")
>>> parser.print_help() 

usage: argparse.py [-h]

A foo that bars

optional arguments:  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

And that's how you'd foo a bar
```

Refer to the documentation (linked above) for more information.

Comment: Is there a way to insert it without using the description? I'm actually trying to add it at the bottom of the help message.

Comment: Yes, if you open the documentation you'll see the "epilog" option right below the "description".

Comment: Doesn't work well. All formating (newlines and spaces) are ignored.

Comment: That's a different issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853722/how-to-insert-newlines-on-argparse-help-text