# How to print a multiline version text by argparse module in Python?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

Well, I'm using `argparse` module but have found that a multiline text as the version information won't be shown well. The result shows that the '\n' will be changed into space ' '.
Example:

```py
import argparse
ver_text = 'This is the\nversion text!'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version=ver_text)
```

```sh
$ python test.py -v
```

Result:

```
This is the version text!
```

So this is the problem. I wonder how to handle it. Thanks very much!

Comment: as i remember there should be some option in argparse for `\n` this but you would have to read in documentation. But it could be for formatting `help` text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python argparse: How to insert newline in the help text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853722/python-argparse-how-to-insert-newline-in-the-help-text)

Comment: tl;dr `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)`

Answer (score 5):

If I use

```
ArgumentParser(formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
```

then it displays `\n`

```
import argparse
from argparse import RawTextHelpFormatter

ver_text = 'This is the\nversion text!'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version=ver_text)
parser.parse_args(['-v'])
```

But I don't know if other strings will work in correct way.

Comment: All strings look well. Thanks for your answer! XD